# What is the first movie to show slicing through a candle to show sword prowess

Tags: first-appearance, cinema-history

The nearest I can find is [The Mark of Zorro](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032762/). It shows the villain (played by the wonderful [Basil Rathbone](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001651/)) slicing through a candle with rage and then the hero slicing through a candle but seemingly missing. Afterward the villain laughs and then the hero shows how good he really is.

This is the oldest movie I can find that shows this. Are there any older movies?

Comment: Ugh... Lamenting on the fact that i thought it was mask of zorro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted by the OP, the [Basil Rathbone scene from 1940](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032762/) could well be the earliest example of a candle being sliced in two by a sword purely to showcase his prowess. The 1925 movie, [Don Q, Son of Zorro](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0015758/), starring Douglas Fairbanks also features candle slicing, albeit with a whip.

While I have not seen it, [this blog](http://duncanmhamilton.com/my-favourite-swashbucklers-part-iii/) notes that the Errol Flynn swashbuckler, [The Sea Hawk](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0033028/), also features a scene where:

> Flynn slices through the candle sticks, quite why I couldn't say for sure, but it looks pretty cool!

The film was released in July, 1940 while *The Mark of Zorro* was released in November of the same year.

Comment: I finally found a copy of The Sea Hawk to watch and the main character attacks a villain and when the villain ducks the slice goes through three candles instead. It did look cool but not quite the scene I was hoping for. It seems that *The Mark of Zorro* is the first instance :)